# Django - Unit testing a form containing recaptcha

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, recaptcha, captcha

I am trying to write a unit test for a form containing recaptcha:

My contact view looks like this:

```py
@check_recaptcha
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid() and request.recaptcha_is_valid:

            f.save(request)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Thanks for submitting feedback!")


            return redirect('contact')
    else:
        f = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'cms/contact.html', {'form': f})
```

The decorator `check_recaptcha()` is defined like this:

```py
def check_recaptcha(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.recaptcha_is_valid = None

        if settings.DEBUG:
            request.recaptcha_is_valid = True
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            data = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
            result = r.json()
            if result['success']:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = True
            else:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = False
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')

        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view
```

And the code to test the contact form looks like this:

```py
class TestContactForm(TestCase):

    def test_can_send_feedback(self):
        data = {
            "name": "tom",
            "email": "tom@test.com",
            "subject": "A test subject",
            "message": "Hello jerry",
        }

        response = self.client.post(reverse('contact'), data=data)
        self.assertEqual(Feedback.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('contact'))
```

The test run perfectly fine if I remove `request.recaptcha_is_valid` condition in the `contact` view. Is there a way to get rid of captcha during testing?

Answer (score 0):

There a specific keys for testing recaptcha forms: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do

Otherwise you can also mock your resquests response with https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Additional to hendrikschneider answer(https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do). If you want to test on unit testing, for setup `GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY` V3 use the test secret key (create a separate key for testing environments), V2 secret key use `6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe` like the faq mentioned. Remember to set your domain to `localhost` if using V3

For `g-recaptcha-response` set it to anything will do